# How to properly link 2 phone cables with different diameter?

Tags: telephone, phone-wiring

I'm thinking about how to link 2 cables .

I have the phone line from my provider that comes in with a cable made of 2 internal strands, each of this strands is 0.75mm on average along all the length of the wire ( just the copper section, of course each strand has white or red insulation ) . The cable has open heads .

I would like to rewire my phone and data lines inside my house and use ethernet / rj45 / FTP cabling for everything .

The main problem is that the phone cable from the provider is basically 21-20 AWG, the internal strands of an FTP cable are way smaller in diameter, basically half of that: how I can link the 2 ?

The first thought was about LSA cabling, but 0.7-0.8mm are too much for most LSA systems, I haven't tried yet in practice, but basically all the most reputable brands produce networking plugs and junction box around the 26-22 AWG mark .

A patch panel is the same thing since all the patch panels I know of are based on LSA style type of internal wiring .

On this line I have both data and voice and I would like to use something made of copper, with a really good insulation / shielding , possibly with IP67/IP68 protection .

tl;dr

the provider's cable is 2x thicker than a single strand of your typical FTP cable and I want to do a good job with it

PS

I don't want to fiddle with the provider's cable, I just want to plug it in somewhere and forget about it, so I can't just crimp an rj11 plug on it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the line from your provider is, or should be, terminated in a "customer interface" or "network interface device" which also usually have surge-suppression for the telephone line built-in - and those have large threaded studs or other screw connectors for the larger wires to connect to.

[image: network interface device image from polpo.org]

[image: Network interface image from cromwell-intl.com]

I frankly find it odd that this would be missing, as it's remarkably standardized across many countries; and the surge-supression is not something you should be without, since telephone lines can pick up all sorts of unpleasant things in thunderstorms.

Comment: the short story is : my provider "provides" just the wiring up to the first "junction box" in my house, please note that I didn't wrote "apartament", but house / building, and this means that I have to buy something that I can place inside the hall / entrance of the building . The reason why I was going for a patch panel is because a pp offers some shielding and grounding and it's a proven design for data / voice, the only problem is the diameter of the cable of my provider . Can you name this 2 things in this 2 photos so I can make a search with Google or Amazon ?

Comment: I already did name them.

Comment: I was assuming that "customer interface" or "network interface device" were generic names and not really specific ones, sorry for the incomprehension and thanks for the tips .

Answer (score 1):

When making data wire repairs I use [these crimp](https://www.elvessupply.com/Dolphin-Components-DC100S-_p_360485.html?gclid=CLL336inwc4CFY17fgodRDQB3w) connectors with the dialectic gell. Just push the insulated wires into the connector they don't need to be stripped and crush with pliers. The style with the gell work quite well in damp locations . There are cheaper ones that do not have the gell but these are for indoor dry locations. These have a bunch if tiny teeth inside that contacts the wire to make the connection. I used to keep both kinds in my repair kit but now only purchase the type with the gell.

Comment: thanks, I'm taking note. I didn't knew about the existance of this kind of connectors but they look functionally similar to this one http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mq2CyT7DAHZVKAxU5mI40og.jpg aren't they ?

Comment: Yes those are similar and I have used them in the past. They work well but a bit more expensive here in the U.S.